# Wordpress Search Function

Tags: wordpress, search

We have a search function on one of our sites - http://www.artisansofdevizes.com/products

At the moment the tick box filters etc work ok.

But the free search box will only return a value if the specific search keywords are used (product names).

Is there a way to enable a more free flowing search ability, where best match based on the search criterial will return accurate results?

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of free autocomplete / search services available on the internet. One of them is rockitsearch.com . So basically you can create an index within the service and use this index on your sites for free.